# Google Classroom Share Button - Body Parameter

Tags: google-classroom

the Google Classroom SHARE BUTTON body parameter has stopped working since the launch of the enriched text option. Have a look at the sample below. It worked before the release of the new functionality, it stopped them.

Any help? Thanks a lot!

------
<g:sharetoclassroom url="http://url-to-share" title="Title" body="What you need to explain to stutent" size="32"></g:sharetoclassroom>

Comment: Thanks for raising the flag! The same issue for me. Can't find any notification or notes in the documentation about it https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton
It was working fine with no changes a few days ago. Appreciate any help